# Using predicate logic, prove $(\forall x) [P(x) \land Q(x)]\to (\forall x)P(x) \land (\forall x)Q(x)$.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$$(\forall x) [P(x) \land Q(x)]\to (\forall x)P(x) \land (\forall x)Q(x)$$

I am having trouble understanding predicate calculus proofs. I am a beginner. Any help is welcomed!

Comment: What rules do you have available to you? How exactly are they defined?  That could make a big difference as to hwta the proof will eventually look like.

Comment: What have *you* tried, and where exactly did you get stuck? Show us your effort!

Comment: As shown by the answers, there are quite a few different proof systems out there, with different names for the rules, or different ways to apply them.  It would be useful if you indicate what your system uses.

Answer (score 2):

You need to think of proofs in natural language. $P$ and $Q$ are properties about elements in your universe of discourse. The statement says that "If both $P$ and $Q$ are valid for every $x$, then $P$ is valid for every $x$, and $Q$ is valid for every $x$".

So to prove it, in natural language and in a **very** pedantic manner, would be something like

> 1. Suppose that both $P$ and $Q$ are valid for every $x$. We need to prove that, given an arbitrary $x$, $P$ is valid for $x$, and also that given any arbitrary $y$, $Q$ is valid at $x$.
> 2. We first will prove that, given arbitrary $x$, $P$ is valid at $x$. So let $x$ be arbitrary. By hypothesis, $P$ and $Q$ are valid for $x$.
> 3. In particular, $P$ is valid for $x$.
> 4. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $P$ is valid for all $x$.
> 5. (and 6.) And similarly, $Q$ is also valid for all $x$.
> 6. Therefore, $P$ is valid for all $x$, and $Q$ is valid for all $x$.

The formal proof is simply writing down the argument above in the language of first-order logic. Notice that the very first paragraph is a realization of the Deduction Theorem. That is, let us prove that
$$\forall x(P(x)\land Q(x))\vdash(\forall xP(x))\land(\forall xQ(x))$$

The proof follows:

> 1. $$\forall x(P(x)\land Q(x))\tag{hypothesis}$$
> 2. $$P(x)\land Q(x)\tag{Universal instantiation of 1.}$$
> 3. $$P(x)\tag{simplification of 2.}$$
> 4. $$\forall xP(x)\tag{universal generalization of 3.}$$
> 5. $$Q(x)\tag{simplification of 3.}$$
> 6. $$\forall xQ(x)\tag{universal generalization of 5.}$$
> 7. $$(\forall xP(x))\land(\forall xQ(x))\tag{conjunction of 4. and 6.}$$

This proves $\forall x(P(x)\land Q(x))\vdash (\forall x P(x))\land(\forall xQ(x))$. By the Deduction Theorem,
$$\hspace{0pt}\vdash\forall x(P(x)\land Q(x))\to\left[(\forall xP(x))\land(\forall xQ(x))\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

You could  use the [method of analytic tableaux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux), like so

[image]

The tree was generated by this site: https://www.umsu.de/trees/.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formal proof using Fitch natural deduction:

[image]

The proof idea is similar to the one provided by Luiz Codeiro, but if we assume a rule system with a full set of elimination and introduction rules for all of the connectives, we don't need to make use of the deduction theorem: Instead we can show the derivability of the implication directly in one natural deduction proof by applying the $\to$-introduction rule as a last step after the subderivation of the consequent $\forall Px \land \forall Qx$ from the assumption $\forall x(P(x) \land Q(x))$.
In addition, we have different choice for the order of $\land$-eliminiation and $\forall$-introduction: We could do the $\forall$-introduction on $P(a)$ directly after extracting it from the conjunction and treat $Q(a)$ afterwards, or first eliminate both conjuncts and then apply $\forall$ on them, like I did; that is, we could swap the order of the lines 4 and 5.